# Magento2 : Layer Navigation Product Collection Returns Inconsistent Results

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-collection

I'm running code on my Product List page. First time on page get 4 items. if I refresh page, I'll get 6, then 4, then 5 etc. I can't see any reason for this. I checked my query and it's always same. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

```
$products = $layer->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('part_number',array('in'=>$numbers))
                    ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```

Comment: What is `$numbers` in your code? how do you get it?

Comment: They are a list of part numbers that I get from another api call. This is set up as an attribute. The query from Magento DB always returns 18 items, but when I view $products->getItems(). Sometimes it has 4,5, or 6 items. It varies almost every time

Comment: If you can log your collection query with code `$product->printLogQuery(true);` after you get collection and match each time it changes item count.

Comment: Did that, the queries are exact but one returned 4 and the next returned 5. It's the internal _items array that keeps changing

Comment: Do you have URL for this? Because of queries are correct it should give you same results.

Comment: It appears that isLoaded returns true with a different query then the one that prints. The query returns with a query that include a tmp_search.... table

Comment: load calls renderFilters which adds the search_tmp filter, then on subsequent loads, even though my select is different, the results are still loaded from the first query. Now I have to figure out why the full text renderer is giving me weird results that seem to vary each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this was due to a couple issues. Trying to filter on an attribute that wasn't added to search_results.xml. I added that as a field and it still didn't work at first, but then I changed the code to use addFieldToFilter and it worked. I was also trying to use a custom collection and it didn't support paging. I changed it back to the productCollection.